# fade in fade out for an images array swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a global variable of images array

```
public var images = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"]
```

I want to show it fade in fade out each image after 2 seconds when I click the button. Means when the image "11" appear first, after 2 seconds, it will fade out, and then the image "12" will fade in and so on. But my code doesn't work well.

here is my code:

```
@IBAction func playAutomaticPhotoImages(sender: AnyObject) {

    for image in images {
      photoImageView.hidden = false
      photoImageView.alpha = 1.0
      UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
        self.photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
        self.photoImageView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: {
          (value: Bool) in
          self.photoImageView.hidden = true
          self.photoImageView.alpha = 0.0
      })
    }
  }
```

here is my image:

[image]

Comment: The delay needs to increase, it's a delay from now, not a delay from the end of some previous animation (which isn't known in your loop)

Comment: I edit like this UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { ... But it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is that, the for loop will schedule all the animations to run, simultaneously. One way to achieve what you want is to use the completion block to notify you when one animation is complete so the next one can begin.

Comment: really you should use a repeating timer so you can cancel (manage) it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this multiple ways

**Choice -1**

```
@IBAction func playAutomaticPhotoImages(sender: AnyObject) {

 self.animateImages()

 }

fun animateImages()
{
  var count: Int = 0

  var images = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"]

var image: UIImage = images[(count % images.count)]

UIView.transitionWithView(self.photoImageView, duration: 2.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {() -> Void in
self.photoImageView.image = image
}, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
self.animateImages()
// once finished, repeat again
count++
})

 }
```

**Choice-2**

```
 @IBAction func playAutomaticPhotoImages(sender: AnyObject) {

 self.animateImages(0) /*call animageImage with parameter number as image number as i user image name as "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"*/

 }



    func animateImages(no:Int)
    {
        var Number:Int = no
        let t:NSTimeInterval = 1;
        let t1:NSTimeInterval = 0;
        var name:String = "yourImageName\(Number).png"
        self.photoImageView!.alpha = 0.4
        self.photoImageView!.image = UIImage(named:name);

        //code to animate bg with delay 2 and after completion it recursively calling animateImage method 
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {() in 
                                                       self.photoImageView!.alpha = 1.0;
                                                   }, 
                                         completion: {(Bool) in
                                                      Number++;

                                                      self. animateImages(Number); 
                                                   })
    }
}
```

**Choice-3**

```
@IBAction func playAutomaticPhotoImages(sender: AnyObject) {

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "crossfade", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


photoImageView.animationImages = images

photoImageView.animationDuration = 2
photoImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0        
photoImageView.startAnimating()


 }




func crossfade() {
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {() -> Void in
    photoImageView.alpha = !photoImageView.alpha
}, completion: {(done: Bool) -> Void in
    //
})
}
```

Comment: I am not tried this once, but it works fine on objective -C

Comment: your code error and I edit this line like this: let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: images[(count % images.count)])!
But it doesn't work, it doesn't show anything

Comment: Wait, in your choice 2, when it go through all images array, it crash
fatal error: Array index out of range

Answer (score 0):

you should begin the next image show animation when the previous animation complete.if you put the animation code in the `for` scope,the animation transaction will be sent the runloop at a time. so your view will not be normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Swift :

```
class ImageLoader {
var images = ["Image1","Image2","Image3","Image4"]

var copyImages : [String] = []

var loadNextImage : Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if loadNextImage{
            // Reload the array if its empty.
            if copyImages.count == 0 {
                copyImages = images
            }

            // Load next image here.
            let theImage = copyImages.removeFirst()
            
            // Pass the image to the load function.
            loadNextAnimationImage(theImage)
        }
    }
}

func loadNextAnimationImage(theImage : String){
    
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        // Do your animation action here.
        print ("The i")
        
        }) { (animationComplete) -> Void in
            if animationComplete {
                
                self.loadNextImage = true
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I run, it show error here: let theImage = images.removeFirst()
fatal error: can't remove first element from an empty collection

Comment: What is the error? The code above is just an indication of how the logic can be implemented. You need to ensure that you are using the correct data types etc.

Comment: How about when it go through all the images array, it will crash?

Comment: Updated the answer to check for blank Array and reload it if tis empty.

Comment: It still doesn't work, if you removefirst, the next time when click play button, does it work again?

Comment: Why dont you take the general idea or direction that folks have suggested here and try to implement the solution? Please dont expect a folks here to provide a complete line by line code with description handling all possible scenario. You have to try that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = ["1","2","3"]

private func showImage( at index : Int) {
    if slideImage1.image != nil {
        slideImage1.fadeOut { (finished: Bool) in
            self.slideImage1.image = UIImage(named: self.images[index])
            self.slideImage1.fadeIn()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5) {
                self.showImage(at: (index + 1) % self.images.count)
            }
        }
    } else {
        slideImage1.image = UIImage(named: images[index])
        slideImage1.fadeIn()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5) {
            self.showImage(at: (index + 1) % self.images.count)
        }
    }
}
```

I have used fadeIn() and fadeOut(), To display images from array.

slideImage1 is UIImageView